# What's the best Pigweed variable to check against in a debug build?

Tags: pigweed

In the Cortex-M toolchain I'm trying to do something like this:

```
config("sf2_bootloader") {
  if (debug_build != "") {
    defines = ["SF2_MSS_NO_BOOTLOADER=1"]
  }
}
```

Does Pigweed have a variable like `debug_build`?

Answer (score 0):

Pigweed doesn't provide a Pigweed macro.

You can add a define to a config, and then list it in `default_configs` for your debug toolchain/target to set one up.

There's a few modules that check against `NDEBUG`, but Pigweed doesn't provide a "debug build" that defines it.

Source: https://discord.com/channels/691686718377558037/691686718377558040/955856186748592178